# Jest Test unable to run because of TypeError (issue with hyperHTML?)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, jestjs

I am running into an error while attempting to unit test and I'm not sure what the cause of it is. 
Jest tests will run normally until I need to import functions from the file to test from.

Here is a very watered down version of the jest test I want to run, the require causes the bug that I am encountering.

```
//SigninView.test.js
let SigninRouteHandler = require("../../../../../src/js/Modules/Portal/Signin/SigninView");

test('empty passing test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Here is the error from the console

```
$ jest js/ModulesTests/PortalTests/SigninTests/SigninView.test.js
FAIL  tests/js/ModulesTests/PortalTests/SigninTests/SigninView.test.js

● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: original.cloneNode is not a function

  121 | 
  122 |     render() {
> 123 |         return this.html`
      |                     ^
  124 |         <div class="parts-view-inner" onmouseup="${this.endDragging}">
  125 |             <div class="" id="sidebar-content-container" data-width=${this.state.sidebarWidth}>
  126 |                 ${CurrentBuildViewComponent}

  at setAttribute (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/objects/Updates.js:398:32)
  at Object.create (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/objects/Updates.js:70:22)
  at DocumentFragment.upgrade (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/hyper/render.js:44:27)
  at DocumentFragment.render (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/hyper/render.js:30:13)
  at PartsView.<anonymous> (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/hyper/wire.js:44:13)
  at PartsView.render (src/js/Modules/Parts/PartsView.js:123:21)
  at PartsView.value (node_modules/hyperhtml/cjs/classes/Component.js:102:36)
  at new PartsView (src/js/Modules/Parts/PartsView.js:35:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/App.js:12:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/Modules/Portal/Signin/SigninView.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/js/ModulesTests/PortalTests/SigninTests/SigninView.test.js:2:26)
```

As you can see it stops at some point in the hyperHTML file. Perhaps it's an issue with that?

and this is the code from the error output

```
render() {
    return this.html`
    <div class="parts-view-inner" onmouseup="${this.endDragging}">
        <div class="" id="sidebar-content-container" data-width=${this.state.sidebarWidth}>
            ${CurrentBuildViewComponent}
            <div id="dragbarH" onmousedown="${this.handleHDrag}"></div>
            ${QuickSummaryViewComponent}
        </div>
        <div id="dragbarV" onmousedown="${this.handleVDrag}"></div>
        ${PartsExplorerViewComponent}
    </div>
    `;
}
```

I can run unit tests using jest fine, the only time I encounter problems is when I try to import other files like this.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated! thank you

Comment: Your `SigninView` Component is working fine, when used outside test?

Comment: Yes. Only throws this error when we try testing with jest. We're also trying mocha but we still can't figure out what's wrong.